# c # datatable replace duplicate values with blanks

Tags: c#, loops, datatable

I have a dataset like this. I would like to replace the repeating values with blanks like the second column. So only the first instance of the value is output and the others rows are blank.

```
current output
1       1
1 
1
1
2       2
2       
2
3       3
3
3
3
3
4       4
4
4
4
```

I started with this but the second time in the loop blank does not equal i-1 so I am kind of stuck.

```
for (int i = 1; i < dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    // Compare with previous row using index
    if (dt.Rows[i]["Supplier_No"].ToString().Equals(dt.Rows[i - 1]["Supplier_No"].ToString()))
    {
        dt.Rows[i]["Supplier_No"] = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you filling this `DataSet`, the code above seems like you're using a `DataTable`? Depending on how you're filling this object, why don't you make the changes there and then you wouldn't have to do this?

Comment: If that datatable is the result of a database query, there are almost certainly ways to alter the query to return exactly the table you want, and it will be faster than attempting to fix it after the fact.  This effect is multiplied if the dataset is large, or the repetition counts are high.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to remember what the original value was.

```
string previous = dt.Rows[0]["Supplier_No"].ToString();

for (int i = 1; i < dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    // Compare with previous row using index
    if (dt.Rows[i]["Supplier_No"].ToString().Equals(previous))
    {
        dt.Rows[i]["Supplier_No"] = "";
    }
    else
    {
        previous = dt.Rows[i]["Supplier_No"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: FWIW, if comparing numbers, compare numbers, not strings.

Comment: @Codexer Agreed.  If this was CR, I would have elaborated.  Since it was SO, I mirrored OP's usage.

Comment: I understand, I know it was in the OP question, just something I seen when viewing your answer.

Comment: Perfect. I had almost the same thing before I saw your answer. thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The following code is tested :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;


namespace ConsoleApplication181
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Supplier_No", typeof(int));
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {1});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {1});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {1});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {1});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {1});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {2});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {2});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {2});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {2});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {3});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {3});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {3});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {3});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {3});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {3});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {4});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {4});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {4});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {4});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {4});

            var groups = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x=> x.Field<int>("Supplier_No"));

            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < group.Count(); i++)
                {
                    group.Skip(i).First()["Supplier_No"] = DBNull.Value;
                }
            }

        }

 
    }
   
 
}
```